# What happened to the Applications Menu?

Tags: release-hera, applications, icons, slingshot, menu

When I was running Juno, I could go into Elementary Tweaks and set the number of columns & rows used in the Applications menu.

I couldn't change spacing or icon size, but that was OK. Extra columns & rows made for less pages on the Applications Menu.

For some reason now (with Hera) I can't do this anymore. I've been searching all over the web trying to find out why Elementary Tweaks doesn't do this anymore.

Maybe it moved to somewhere else? So I've also been searching on the interwebs to find anything about changing the Applications Menu. Nada! Nothing! Zilch!

I am currently using 5.1.6 and wonder why such a useful feature would have been removed.

Anybody got any ideas about how to do this simple task in Hera??

Thanks for your help everyone!

Christopher

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of this?:

> What's New?
>
> - Fully updated and working to reflect the changes of elementary OS
>   Juno
> - elementary-tweaks now looks more "elementary"! We've rebuilt elementary tweaks > from the ground up to make it look like a native plug for your system's settings.
> - Fixed: Removed theme-patcher and ***other more dangerous settings that were causing problems***

Answer (score 0):

You could try with https://eos-techs.com/2020/05/14/howto-change-slingshot-to-the-old-style-in-elementary-os/ to get the old look back.

Answer (score 0):

The option to change the number of columns and rows was removed from the launcher. So we can no longer change the launcher size anymore, unfortunately.